# Write from R to Teradata in 3.0

Tags: r, teradata

R3.0 is not compatible with `TeradataR` and there are no plans to update the package or release the source code.

Does anyone have a code snippet that shows how to write a dataframe to a new or existing Teradata table?

```
sql <- "CREATE TABLE teradata.aaa (yr BIGINT, ct BIGINT, tax BIGINT)"  
tbl <- sqlQuery(ch, sql)  # Creates a table, works 
# What syntax to insert a dataframe 'myData' into this table?
```

Comment: Did you try RODBC packages? I use it to pull data from teradata, I never uploaded to teradata tables with it (uploading to db2 or MS SQL Server works great), I assume it will work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I was using RODBC but the `sqlSave` function kept blowing up.  I think it's because the Teradata flavor of SQL is a little different than the standard.

Comment: https://github.com/jeffwong/teradataR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I learned that bulk uploads are not supported.  I had to simply `INSERT` each line of the data frame into the table.

This was time-consuming and I'm going to investigate whether a JDBC connection might be faster.

Comment: Have you looked at `as.td.data.frame` to coerce to a td data frame? (from the TeradataR user guide)