# Bulkload option exporting data from R to Teradata using RODBC

Tags: r, teradata, bulkinsert, rodbc, bulk-load

I have done many researches on how to upload a huge data in .txt through R to Teradata DB. I tried to use RODBC's `sqlSave()` but it did not work. I also followed some other similar questions posted such as:
[Write from R to Teradata in 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931439/write-from-r-to-teradata-in-3-0) OR [Export data frame to SQL server using RODBC package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302514/export-data-frame-to-sql-server-using-rodbc-package) OR [How to quickly export data from R to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190744/how-to-quickly-export-data-from-r-to-sql-server).

However, since Teradata somehow is structured differently than MS SQL server, most of those options suggested are not applicable to my situation. 
I know that there is a TeradataR package available but it has not been updated since like 2-3 years ago.

So here are my 2 main problems I am facing:
1. How to bulk load (all records at once) data in .txt format to Teradata using R if there is any way. (So far I only tried using SAS to do so, but I need to explore this in R) 
2. The data is big like 500+ MB so I cannot load it through R, I am sure there is a way to go around this but directly pull data from server.

Here is what I tried according to one of posts but this was for MS SQL server:

```
toSQL = data.frame(...) #this doesn't work for me cause its too big.
write.table(toSQL,"C:\\export\\filename.txt",quote=FALSE,sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=FALSE);

    sqlQuery(channel,"BULK
                INSERT Yada.dbo.yada
                FROM '\\\\<server-that-SQL-server-can-see>\\export\\filename.txt'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'
                )");
```

*Note: there is an option in Teradata to insert/import data but that is the same as writing millions of rows of Insert statements.

Sorry that I do not have sample codes at this point since the package that I found wasn't the right one that I should use.

Anyone has similar issues/problems like this?

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Use Teradata utilities for this - multiload (mload) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you figured out how to do this but I second Andrew's solution.  If you have Teradata installed on your computer you can easily run the FastLoad Utility from the shell.

So I would:

1. export by data frame to a txt file (Comma separated)
2. create my fastload script and call the exported txt file from within the fastload scrip (you can learn more about it [here](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities%2FB035-2411%25E2%2580%2590116K%2F2411Ch01.03.7.html))
3. run the shell command referencing my fastload script.

   ```
   setwd("pathforyourfile")
   write.table(mtcars, "mtcars.txt", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE,quote= FALSE, na = "NA",col.names = FALSE)
   shell("fastload < mtcars_fastload.txt")
   ```

I hope this sorts your issue.  Let me know if you need help especially on the fastloading script.  More than happy to help.